# Proof set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Question: is the set $V=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\le 4\}$ bounded?

I used the definition: an $m > 0$ exists s.t. for every $a = (x,y) \in V$ we have $\|a\|\le m$.

So my result was $\|a\|= \sqrt {x^2+y^2}\le x^2+y^2\le 4$

I want to know if this was the correct way to do it.

Comment: No, this is not correct. An error is pointed out in an answer. Another: You use the same symbol, $x $, to mean two different things (a 2-dimensional vector, and one of its coordinates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $$x^2+y^2 =0.25$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0.5 >x^2+y^2$$

To correct the mistake. just note that

$$\left\| a \right\| \leq 2$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\|x\|$=<2? Do you mean i have to square $m$ always when i apply $\|x\|$=<m?

Comment: $x^2+y^2 \leq 4 \implies \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 2$ right?

Comment: Yes i see that but why did you chane $\|x\|$ into $\|a\|$ and the example you give implies that my answer is not correct? 0,5 is greater than 0,25. Why should i choose m=2? Why cant i use m=4 as the question implies?

Comment: A symbol should only mean a single thing. consider for example the vector $(1,1)$, when someone asked you what is $x$, I wouldn't know whether you should answer $1$ as the first coordiante is $1$ or $(1,1)$. 

Note that for your original attempt, you wrote $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq x^2+y^2$ which is not true in general.

Comment: If we have $\| a\| \leq 2$, we have $\| a\| \leq 4$, of course, you can use $4$ as well. Note that the geometrical meaning of object $V$ would be a disk, do you know the radius?

Comment: $\|x\|$=$\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ right? That is according to the definition. Now i know that the set can be 4 maximum. The set is $x^2+y^2$=<4 i have to work to that expression right? So what will it change if i use m=2 instead of m=4. And i know now that in my original attempt i could proof it then. How can m=2 correct that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60426/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-mark).

Answer (score 1):

With the norm

$$\|(x,y)\|=\sup (|x|,|y|) $$
we have

$$x^2\le x^2+y^2\le 4\implies |x|\le 2$$
and
$$y^2\le x^2+y^2\le 4\implies |y|\le 2$$
$$\implies \sup (|x|,|y|)\le 2$$
$$\implies \|(x,y)\|\le 2$$

Comment: Why didnt we learn such trick definitions of sup|x|,|y|=||x,y||????? I am getting angry that those teachers dont say these things

Comment: $\sup(|x|,|y|)=\| (x,y) ^T\|_\infty$ there are many different types of norms. $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\| (x,y) ^T\|_2$. In general, $(x^p+y^p)^\frac1p = \| (x,y) ^T\|_p$. fun readings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

If this set wasn't bounded then the euclidean distance function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be unbounded. Hence, given any $M>0$, there exists $(x,y) \in V$ such that $d(\vec{0},(x,y))>M$. If we take $M >4$ then we get a contradiction since equivalently we have $V = \{(x,y): d(\vec{0},(x,y)) \leq 4\}$.